# Do BackgroundJob of aspnetboilerplate use UnitOfWork to run Execute method

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I checked source code of [BackgroundJobManager](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/master/src/Abp/BackgroundJobs/BackgroundJobManager.cs), but I can't understand that it use UnitOfWork or not?

Do I need to add a `[UnitOfWork]` into `Execute` method?

Answer (score 3):

I found this answer.

Yes, you can add UnitOfWork into Execute method.

Moreover, if you don't do this, EF Lazyload is not working in Execute method.

Ref [GitHub Issue: In BackgroundJob injection IRepository cannot work?](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2285)